# Is there a way to re-calibrate the compass on my Android Galaxy s6, with verizon as my carrier?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, compass, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+

I need to re-calibrate the compass on the my Android Galaxy Edge 6s. I read that I must first go to the secret menu, which can be accessed through the code *#0*# being typed into the dial pad of the phone. I have also found out that verizon has disabled this menu (which would explain why nothing happens when I try using a secret code).

Is there a way to re-calibrate the compass on my Android Galaxy s6, with verizon as my carrier?

Comment: Ditching Verizon would be one way to fix the problem!